# Did Prophet Muhammed (saw) raise a dead man to give the Shahada?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, source-identification, authenticity, shahada

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

In the Friday khutbah the local khateeb imam narrated a hadith. It goes like this.

The mushrik of Mecca didn't believe in the prophethood of our prophet. So they got a dead body of a Mushrik who was on the way to getting buried, and asked the prophet saw to raise him to life and if he succeeded they would all convert to Islam. 
The prophet apparently raised the dead man and the dead man gave shahada that he in fact is the messenger of Allah.

Is this an authentic?

Answer (score 1):

Imam Al-Bayhaqi compiled a 7 volume book called Dala'il al-Nubuwwah (The proofs of Prophethood), in which he listed many miracles of Muhammad (SAW). So if this story is authentic then you have a good chance of finding it there: http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1440

In volume 6, page 50-57  he lists some events involving resurrection of the dead, however these are different from the story you have quoted. The people resurrected are Muslims and it happens after the Hijrah.